# How do I use in $in operator using the 2.0 version of the C# mongodb driver?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I found a lot of examples of how do use $in in the previous mongodb c# driver, but I can not find any examples on how to do it in the 2.0 version.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what you have tried... Some links to the docs: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/driver/definitions/#filter-definition-builder and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/driver/expressions/#in

Answer (score 8):

Use the `AnyIn` operator for the typed version:

`Builders<TDocument>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.Array,searchArray)`

Answer (score 4):

There is `$in` operator in the driver:

```
var inValues = new List<string>() { "value1", "value2" };
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("Field Name", inValues);

// usage of the filter:
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = <get your collection here>
var query = collection.Find(filter)
...
```

where "Field Name" should be replaced with the actual field name used for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out. Here is how to define the Bson document for the Find method:

```
BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(vins)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, how about this

```
var ft = new BsonDocument("ListOfString", new BsonDocument("$in", varString));
var result = myContext.myPOCO.Find(ft);
```