# Why am I getting the error "The serializer for field ... must implement IBsonArraySerializer" when using AnyIn?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I declare a Filter in c# by mongodb like this:

```
var filters = new List<FilterDefinition<Message>>
if (!area.Equals(""))
filters.Add(Builders<Message>.Filter.Eq("Domain", area));
```

and work perfectly when **area** is a single string for example 1. but I want area is 1,2,5,55,this filter work.
In order to this I have changed my filter to this:

```
filters.Add(Builders<Message>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.Domain, area));
```

according [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393696/how-do-i-use-in-in-operator-using-the-2-0-version-of-the-c-sharp-mongodb-driver)

but I got this error :

> The serializer for field 'Domain' must implement IBsonArraySerializer
> and provide item serialization info.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847288/mongodb-c-sharp-implementing-ibsonarrayserializer) but nobody do not answer to this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, you shouyld be using the [$in query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
   filters.Add(Builders<Message>.Filter.In("Domain", new List<int>() { a1, a2 }));
```